# How to customize a method name in lombok

Tags: java, lombok

Does anyone know how to change/customize the method name in lombok?

For example, I would like to change the name `getContributionType()` to `getType()`:

```
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String contributionType;
```

When I want to get contribution type, the method name will be `getContributionType()`. But I would like to change it to:

```
    private String contributionType;

    public String getType() {
        return contributionType;
    }

    public void setType(final String type) {
        this.contributionType = type;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you cannot rename those methods with Lombok. You can however tell it to [strip prefixes](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/Accessors) which probably works in your case though it's not designed for  chopping whole words off :).

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Accessors(prefix="contribution")
private String contributionType;
```

Comment: Upvoting is not 'accepted' :) Please click the tick to accept it.